# Remove contents of variable using c#

Tags: c#

I have this code content

```
string strAttachment_Path=QuestionData.FirstOrDefault().Attachment_Name;

var filepath = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~" + strAttachment_Path));

ViewBag.files = filepath;
```

Now in variable `filepath` there are 3 to 4 paths like

```
d:\Images\content\forum\abc.jpg

d:\Images\content\forum\def.jpg

d:\Images\content\forum\ghi.jpg

d:\Images\content\forum\klj.jpg
```

I want only path `content\forum\klj.jpg`

How can I do this??

Comment: Use a LINQ query on `filepath` - although I'm not sure what your criteria are, exactly ...

Comment: What is the criteria by which you are selecting the content? What makes "klj.jpg" so special?

Comment: You want only that path based on what?  Does it relate to `Attachment_Name` or is it entirely arbitrary?

Comment: @CharlesMager it is attachment_name

Comment: content is folder name...klg.jpg is name of the file..!!

Answer (score 1):

like that:

```
ViewBag.files = filepath.where(x => x.contains("\klj.jpg"));
```

Comment: so this sets `files` to `true` or `false`?  Is that useful?

Comment: Well, he is giving an example probably. Like he needs path only from content onwards.

Comment: yes its example. Actual path is much more longer